# Best way to have a body with 1 dimensional linear only movement in Box2D

Tags: box2d

I have a body that I am using as a paddle, it is expected to move in a vertical fashion and other objects should "bounce off it". The paddle itself should never move horizontally.

According to the docs this sounds like what I want...

> A kinematic body moves under simulation according to its velocity. Kinematic bodies do not respond to forces.

but reading further....

> Static bodies do not collide with other static or kinematic bodies.

So I create two Static Body lines and a box in between. How do I handle the box's movement? I don't think I want a dynamic object because I am only interested in linear moves (I.E. don't want wabbling).

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the second half of your question, it sounds like you still want a kinematic body. Other *dynamic* objects will react to the kinematic body you have created, but the paddle will remain unaffected by colliding with whatever is supposed to bounce off of it. Check out the example found [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2012/05/11/understanding-box2d-kinematic-bodies/).